# .bat opening diffrent file than command

Tags: batch-file

Sooo i have little program that, what you select it starts that server. When I choose "1" it sends you to ffa: it lookst like this:

```
:FFA
cls
color 0F
echo Startuje se FFA!
start %~dp0\servers\ffa\bstart.bat
pause
```

Soo..it should start bstart.bat wich is in same directory, and than go to folder servers, than go to folder ffa and than open file...

BUUUTT! It doesn't open bstart.bat it STARTS THIS: C:\Users\Aleksej\Desktop\AgarioServers

Can somebody explain me whats problem? ***Thanks! <3***

Comment: if `bstart.bat`  you can just use `call bstart.bat` ?

Comment: One of the folders in the path has a space in its name, doesn't it?

Comment: Either `start "" "%~dp0\servers\ffa\bstart.bat"` or as suggested `call "%~dp0\servers\ffa\bstart.bat"` or even just `"%~dp0\servers\ffa\bstart.bat"` (if you don't need to return to the calling batch file).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

The folder there server directory was had special character( i think it was - or something like that), so CMD started Agario not Agario-Servers. Soo...Yea..Thanks for everybody that tried to help me.